# The use of "make fools" in a passive voice

Tags: word-usage

> Some people can be made fools by misleading advertising.

I'd like to know the use of "made fools" in this sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Some people can be made fools by misleading advertising.

The sentence is grammatically correct but it is not really idiomatic. The usual phrase is to [make a fool (out) ***of*** someone](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-fool-out-of-someone). I suppose you could say

*Some people can be made fools of by misleading advertising.*

However that is a little clumsy so I would simply say

*Some people can be fooled by misleading advertising.*

In conclusion, your sentence is not wrong but it isn't particularly good in my opinion.